# Showing that all Kernel functions are symmetric

Tags: functions, lagrange-multiplier, machine-learning

I want to show that any Kernel function is symmetric, i.e. $K(x_i, x_j) = K(x_j, x_i)$.
I am not sure how I should begin, any tips will help, thanks.

Comment: first step is usually a definition check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an aside, usually kernels in statistics or signal processing are symmetric [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)), but since you tag with machine learning, I suppose you are interested in that case, specifically the kernel trick.

Suppose $x,y\in\mathcal{D}$ are data points in the input space. We also have a *feature map* $\Phi:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathscr{P}$, where $\mathscr{P}$ is an inner product space. Then the kernel function $K:\mathcal{D}\times\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by:
$$
K(x,y) = \langle\Phi(x),\Phi(y)\rangle_{\mathscr{P}}
$$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\mathscr{P}}$ is the inner product of $\mathscr{P}$.

The important fact is that $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\mathscr{P}}$ is symmetric. Thus:
$$
K(x,y) = \langle\Phi(x),\Phi(y)\rangle_{\mathscr{P}}
= \langle\Phi(y),\Phi(x)\rangle_{\mathscr{P}} = K(y,x)
$$
so the kernel is symmetric.

Comment: So in machine learning a kernel is an inner product of features?